# Despite Image Size is equal to the one of an image the image still appears smaller

Tags: gimp, resize, dimensions

I have a weird issue I can not wrap my head around.
Using Gimp for my game card design I used the Image Size setup of 825x1125 pixels.
However when I import the card printing template that has the same size it appears smaller then the image size. How can that be? I am super confused.
[image]

Comment: THere are pixels and then there are physical measurements. Thes edont cneptually mix

Comment: Well here I am with pixels in all cases. How can this be a problem?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. If I have a document open in GIMP, and then import a PNG which is the same size as that document, then the size matches exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two tools:

- The "Scale image" dialog is for `Image>Scale image`. This scales the whole image (all layers, channels, paht, existing selection mask...). Initially this dialog display the current image size, which is identical to the one in the "File properties" dialog from your file explorer (on the left).
- The dialog on the far right is the "tool options" for the Rectangle selection tool. It shows the size of the selection marks, and the selection is smaller than the complete image.

[image]

It looks like you are confused by the additional layer with instructions. The layer you should be working with is visible in the background of your image. You can delete the instructions layer, or hide it, or move it to the bottom of the layer stack so that it is no longer in the way.

Comment: I still am confused a bit. The template file says 825x1125 in the file explorer but when imported it is shrinked to 612x844. That is what I do not understand. Why is it being scaled down

Comment: No, what you show means that your imported image 825x1125. These small dimensions are not the dimension of your image, they are the dimension of the explanation card image, see my image above. The dimension of your image are also displayed in Gimp's title bar, and in the side rulers...

Comment: Ok try to explain it again. The explaination card dimension is 825x1125px says the file explorer. My project/image says (in the title bar) 825x1125. When I import the explaination card it appears smaller (see my screenshot). Why is it shrinked?

Comment: How do you "import" the card?

Comment: drag n drop @xenoid

Comment: Try File>Open as layers, same problem? And if you drop the file on the toolbox to make Gimp open it as a separate image, is that image 825x1125?